# Input Validation for an integer in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, parsing, validation, datagridview

I'm able to use the code below to check whether or not a user inputs a string in a datagridview cell. If the user inputs a string a message pops up to tell them "only numeric entries are allowed". This is exactly what I want my code to do. However if I try to use this code in a column of data populated with numbers I get an error message that says "error happened, parsing commit". If anyone is able to figure out what the issue is here I would greatly appreciate it!

```
If (e.ColumnIndex = 3) Then 'checking numeric value for column 3 only
        Dim value As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
        For Each c As Char In value
            If Not Char.IsDigit(c) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter numeric Value")
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = 3 'This will set the defaultvalue of the datagrid cell in question to the value of "3"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution not only checks for non-integer values it also works for every column populated with numbers for the entire datagridview. Also if the user inputs a non-integer if will supply a default value for the datagridviewcell, this default value is the previous number.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DataError(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) _
Handles DataGridView1.DataError

    If StrComp(e.Exception.Message, "Input string was not in a correct format.") = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a numeric Value") 
        'This will change the number back to original
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = " "
    End If




End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this in cellvalidating event ...

```
If (e.ColumnIndex = 3) Then 'checking numeric value for column 3 only

    If Not Isnumeric(e.Formatted.Value) Then

        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter numeric Value")
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = 3 'This will set the defaultvalue of the datagrid cell in question to the value of "3"
        Exit Sub

    End If

End If
```

Comment: I'm not following this. Can you explain?

Comment: it says that the "e.columnindex" is not part of the EditingControlShowing

Comment: Sorry about that. So I'm trying to get an error message to pop up when I type a string into the datagridview.

Comment: @stackexchange12 .. what err msg ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the code you included is supposed to do, but it does nothing for me. I want a simple message box to pop up is a user inputs a letter into the datagridview cell to tell the user that he/she cannot input letters into the field. Then I want a default value "3" to populate the datagridviewcell after the message

Comment: @stackexchange12 .. So we'll do in your way .. try this

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I'll give you a +1 for all your work.